# ASCII tables using unicode chars

Tags: linux, bash, unicode

Nowadays most of the terminals we use are able to display unicode symbols. Thus, this box:

```
+--------------+
| Hello World! |
+--------------+
```

can easily be rewritten like this using unicode chars:

```
┌──────────────┐
│ Hello World! │
└──────────────┘
```

Several command-line tools such as `boxes` or the Perl CPAN module `Text::ASCIITable` can draw regular ASCII boxes without unicode chars.

My question is for which reason should I avoid using unicode chars (at least after checking if `$LANG` contains utf8)?

Disclaimer: I'm asking for a pragmatic analysis of the problem not any personal opinion cuz some people may think this question is a primarily opinion-based question.

Comment: Depends completely on what your application is for, and what your users expect/want. If it's a fancy command line GUI, do whatever. If it's meant to be used in scripts, keep it plain, ASCII7 text and easily parsable. (But that's just my sysadmin-ish opinion.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason why using “Unicode characters” in the sense implied in the question (i.e. characters outside the ASCII range) is that not all fonts support them. Secondarily, not all programs support them, but this point is losing significance.

When you render characters in a font that does not contain them, they are typically replaced by small rectangles or similar indicators of missing glyphs.

If you can ensure that your software will be used only in environments where the font used to display you character graphics will contain all the characters needed, in acceptable shape, there should be no reason to avoid using non-ASCII characters.

However, the details of rendering will depend on the font used and on the parameters of rendering. For example, box drawing characters do not always join the intended way. On the other hand, even when they don’t, the result is usually better than using ASCII only.

Comment: I'll add that in the non-windows world most systems ship with DejaVu or a derivative (like the one Apple commissioned for OSX) and DejaVu does include brow drawing characters (and many other symbols most other fonts didn't bother with, that's why DejaVu become so popular)